# Bootstrap - hook in image gallery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been working with this site (http://cee.cgreen.ca/index.php?page=designs) (this is a prototype), but bootstrap always seems to be wonky. There always some hook that catches the products into one for its own row etc. I can't seem to figure it out. ;-;

```
    // HTML
<div id="products">
    <div class="span4"> //twitter span
    <div class="product-grid"> //contained image
    <div class="product-grid-item">
    <div class="product-link" title="Pin this!">

    <img src="images/designs/shirt.png" class="product-photo">

    <div class="over-wrapper" style="opacity: 0; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="over-content" style="opacity: 0; display: block;"><br><br><br>

    <a href="link" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/pinthis.png" style="margin:auto;"></a> 

    </div></div></div></div></div>

/** CSS **/
#products {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px "proxima-nova";
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width:100%;
}

.product-grid{
  color: #666666;
  margin:10px;
}

.generated-height .product-grid-item {
  width: 177px;
  position: absolute;

  bottom: 0;

  }

.product-grid img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.product-grid a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #333333;

  }

.product-grid .product-link{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  /* for ie6: */
  width: 100%;
  }

.product-grid .product-link .over{

    position: Absolute;    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.product-photo{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.ie6 .product-grid{ overflow: hidden; }

.span4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.row-fluid .span4 {
  width: 31.91489%;
  *width: 31.8617%;
}
```

Comment: Please state what exactly the problem is what is the desired result.

Comment: I think you'll want to load the `bootstrap-responsive.css` as well. And you need to close your rows after you reach a total span of 12 (where you put the comment `row 2`in your html)

Comment: The bootstrap is loaded (responsive.css) via the index.php page where all the spans are there and such. I have a picture of the problem. It like's the rows are completely fine and there's a malfunction every five rows. Ex:
http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/9850/iu7i.jpg

I tried the 12 row thing. Didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

For the product section, you have 6 span4s in each row.

Spans should add up to 12 in each row, so change this to 3 span4s for each row , and do away with your custom CSS

```
.span4 {
 width: 300px;
}
```